# Matching an extracting country name from character string in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, dplyr, stringr, data-processing

I've been scraping review data from a website, and in the process I am able to get a vector of character strings that contain the username, number of reviews, review date, and country info. They look roughly like this

```
raw <- c("Anna (1025) - North Carolina, USA - DEC 20, 2017", 
"James (10) - - MEXICO - NOV 22, 2017", 
"Susane (222) - Oulu, FINLAND - JUNE 1, 2016", 
"Alex (20000) - SOUTH KOREA- MAR 11, 2015")
```

So far I can extract the names, review numbers, and dates as those are at defined positions or have consistent formatting.  The issue is that the country name formatting is not consistently located, and the various data points within each string are not consistently separated by commas or dashes.  Just extracting upper case strings runs into the issue of missing countries or those with two parts to their name.

The maps package contains a country list.  Is there a way that I can use `str_extract_all` in `stringr` to find matches within the country list vector and extract just that?

Comment: You could create the regular expression search string by combining all of the country names: `pat = paste(iso3166$ISOname, collapse="|")`. Then `str_extract_all(raw, regex(pat, ignore.case=TRUE))`.

Comment: This sounds very specific to your data set, would need more to test possibly

Answer (score 5):

You could do this using `maps` library, as below:

```
library(maps)

## Loading country data from package maps
data(world.cities)

raw <- c("Anna (1025) - North Carolina, USA - DEC 20, 2017", 
     "James (10) - - MEXICO - NOV 22, 2017", 
     "Susane (222) - Oulu, FINLAND - JUNE 1, 2016", 
     "Alex (20000) - SOUTH KOREA- MAR 11, 2015")

###Removing punctuation
raw <- gsub("[[:punct:]\n]","",raw)

# Split data at word boundaries
raw2 <- strsplit(raw, " ")

# Match on country in world.countries
CountryList_raw <- (lapply(raw2, function(x)x[which(toupper(x) %in% toupper(world.cities$country.etc))]))

do.call(rbind, lapply(CountryList_raw, as.data.frame))

#      X[[i]]
#1        USA
#2     MEXICO
#3    FINLAND
```

> This works. However, you would need to fix the name of the country that has multiple words in it later. For example, in this case, SOUTH KOREA. It's because `strsplit` is splitting the words and this is the reason it couldn't match SOUTH KOREA.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

I used the `raw` data and transformed it into a data frame. Then, column by column, I extract the needed information using a combination of regular expressions and row iterations.

## Import Necessary Packages and Raw Data

To follow the tutorial, you'll need to install the following packages installed:

- [`BBmisc`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/BBmisc/index.html): Miscellaneous helper functions for and from B. Bischl and some other guys, mainly for package development.
- [`maps`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maps/index.html): Draw Geographical Maps.
- [`magrittr`](http://magrittr.tidyverse.org/): set of operators which make your code more readable.
- [`purrr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/index.html): A complete and consistent functional programming toolkit for R.

No need to use the `install.packages()` function if you have all of these already.

```
install.packages( pkgs = c(  "BBmisc", "maps", "magrittr", "purrr" ) )
library( BBmisc )
library( maps )
library( magrittr )
library( purrr )

raw <- c("Anna (1025) - North Carolina, USA - DEC 20, 2017", 
         "James (10) - - MEXICO - NOV 22, 2017", 
         "Susane (222) - Oulu, FINLAND - JUNE 1, 2016", 
         "Alex (20000) - SOUTH KOREA- MAR 11, 2015")
```

## Import Raw Data

```
raw <- c("Anna (1025) - North Carolina, USA - DEC 20, 2017", 
         "James (10) - - MEXICO - NOV 22, 2017", 
         "Susane (222) - Oulu, FINLAND - JUNE 1, 2016", 
         "Alex (20000) - SOUTH KOREA- MAR 11, 2015")
```

## Declare Four Columns

Given the data stored in `raw`, four columns felt appropriate to create:

- `user_name`: name of the user
- `user_review_number`: the identification number associated with the user's review
- `user_country`: the user's country
- `user_review_date`: the date - in Month Day, Year format - the user's review was created

  ```
  raw <- data.frame( user_name = raw
         , user_review_number = raw
         , user_country = raw
         , user_review_date = raw
         , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
         )
  ```

## Regular Expressions

[Regular Expressions](http://www.pnotepad.org/docs/search/regular_expressions/) allow complicated and flexible search/replace using a specific syntax. They are used to extract the relevant data from within the `raw` data set.

## Identify raw$user_name

This column contains the user's name just before the parentheses.

```
raw$user_name <- strsplit( x = raw$user_name
                           , split = "\\(|\\)"
                           , fixed = FALSE 
                           )
# keep only the first element from each list, then unlist to obtain a character vector
raw$user_name <- 
  purrr::map( .x = raw$user_name, .f = 1 ) %>%
  unlist()

# remove trailing whitespace
raw$user_name <- trimws( x = raw$user_name
                         , which = "right"
                         )
```

## Identify raw$user_review_number

This column contains the user's review number, which is an integer with anywhere from 1-10 digits in between two parentheses.

```
raw$user_review_number <- strsplit( x = raw$user_review_number
                                    , split = "\\(|\\)"
                                    , fixed = FALSE 
                                    )
# keep only the second element from each list, then unlist to obtain a character vector
# and cast as integer
raw$user_review_number <- 
  purrr::map( .x = raw$user_review_number, .f = 2 ) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  as.integer()
```

## Identify raw$user_country

This column is a bit tricker. Some countries are separated by a comma, others contain two-part names (i.e. SOUTH KOREA), some are abbreviations (i.e. USA), and some contain state information (i.e. North Carolina, USA).

There's a hundred ways to do this, but the logic I used contains the following:

- multiple string splits to account for the variety of ways country information is stored
- cross-referencing given country names with the built-in data set [`maps::iso3166` (see page 9 in the PDF)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maps/maps.pdf), which contains 3,166 country codes from the [International Standards Organizations (ISO)](https://www.iso.org/about-us.html).

See code below.

```
# first, split by the parentheses
raw$user_country <- strsplit( x = raw$user_country
                                    , split = "\\(|\\) "
                                    , fixed = FALSE 
)
# second, keep only the third elements from each list, then unlist to obtain character vector
raw$user_country <- 
  purrr::map( .x = raw$user_country, .f = 3 ) %>%
  unlist()
# third, split by the dash marks, either one or two
raw$user_country <- strsplit( raw$user_country
                          , split = "\\-|\\- \\-"
                          , fixed = FALSE
                          )
# fourth, keep only the second elements from each list, then unlist to obtain character vector
raw$user_country <-
  purrr::map( .x = raw$user_country, .f = 2 ) %>%
  unlist()
# fifth, clear leading and trailing white space
raw$user_country <- trimws( x = raw$user_country
                        , which = "both"
                        )
# sixth, separate states marked by the apperance of a comma
raw$user_country <- strsplit( x = raw$user_country
                         , split = ","
                         , fixed = TRUE
                         ) 
# seventh, make two vectors: 
# one for the first element (which may or not be the state within a country)
maybe.country <- 
  purrr::map( .x = raw$user_country, .f = 1 ) %>%
  unlist()
# one for the second element (which will always be the country)
# note: need to convert NULL elements into NA
definitely.country <-
  purrr::map( .x = raw$user_country, .f = 2, .null = NA ) %>%
  unlist()

# eighth, replace the indices within maybe.country 
#         whose indices in definitely.country are non-NA values
#         with those non-NA values from definitely.country.
# note: this is possible due to the indices within both 
#       maybe.country and definitely.country to be exact equivalents. 
#       (i.e. the 8th element in maybe.country will always align
#        with the 8th element in definitely.country )
maybe.country[
  which( !is.na( definitely.country ) )
  ] <- definitely.country[
    which( !is.na( definitely.country )  )
  ]

# ninth, assign the character vector maybe.country to raw$user_country
raw$user_country <- maybe.country

# tenth, remove all leading and trailing white space
raw$user_country <- trimws( x = raw$user_country
                        , which = "both"
                        )
# eleventh, if the number of letters (length) of any element is more than 3, 
# change the spelling to Capital Case. 
# note: This logic comes from the maps::iso3166 data frame, which contains
#       3,166 country codes from the International Standards Organizations (ISO).
raw$user_country <- ifelse( test = nchar( raw$user_country ) == 2 |
                          nchar( raw$user_country ) == 3
                        , yes = raw$user_country
                        , no = stringr::str_to_title( string = raw$user_country ) 
                        )
# twelfth, check to make sure that all characters are either
# 2 character, 3 character, ISO country codes/names,
# shorter name used in the `maps` package, or the sovereign country
# by ensuring the length of the elements who meet this criteria
# is equal to the length of raw$user_country
length(
  which( raw$user_country %in%  maps::iso3166$a2 |
         raw$user_country %in% maps::iso3166$a3 |
         raw$user_country %in% maps::iso3166$ISOname |
         raw$user_country %in% maps::iso3166$mapname |
         raw$user_country %in% maps::iso3166$sovereignty
       )
) == length( raw$user_country ) # [1] TRUE
```

## Identify raw$user_review_date

Assuming the user's review data is consistently the last bit of text to be stored in each string, here's how you would strip this particular column's data.

```
raw$user_review_date <- strsplit( x = raw$user_review_date
                                  , split = "\\-\\s"
                                  , fixed = FALSE
                                  )

# keep only the last element from each list, 
# unlist to obtain a character vector,
# standardize the dates 
# note: assumes no NAs will appear for date
raw$user_review_date <- 
  purrr::map( .x = raw$user_review_date, .f = BBmisc::getLast ) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  as.Date( format = "%b %d, %Y" )
```

Answer (score 0):

*If*

- country name is *always* written in upper case and
- is the *first word* to appear in all upper case, i.e., names are never written in all caps and the month field is located after the country field

then we can use the following regular expression to extract the country names:

```
"[[:upper:]]{2,}[.]?(\\s[[:upper:]]{2,}[.]?)*"
```

This will work also for country names in multiple parts or where a dot is used to indicate an abbreviation:

```
raw <- c("Anna (1025) - North Carolina, USA - DEC 20, 2017", 
         "James (10) - - MEXICO - NOV 22, 2017", 
         "Susane (222) - Oulu, FINLAND - JUNE 1, 2016", 
         "Alex (20000) - SOUTH KOREA- MAR 11, 2015", 
         "Peter (4711) - KINGDOM OF SOUTH NEVERLAND - DEC 24, 2016", 
         "Paul (0815) - REP. OF NORTH NEVERLAND - DEC 31, 2016")
stringr::str_extract(raw, "[[:upper:]]{2,}[.]?(\\s[[:upper:]]{2,}[.]?)*")
```

> ```
> [1] "USA"                        "MEXICO"                     "FINLAND"                   
> [4] "SOUTH KOREA"                "KINGDOM OF SOUTH NEVERLAND" "REP. OF NORTH NEVERLAND"
> ```

#### Explanation

```
"[[:upper:]]{2,}[.]?(\\s[[:upper:]]{2,}[.]?)*"
```

is looking for a sequence of 2 of more uppercase letters which optionally is followed by a dot. This will catch the country names which consist of only one word.

To catch country anmes consisting of multiple words the expression in parantheses is looking for an arbitrary number of subsequences consisting of white space and another uppercase word with an optional dot.

Note that `stringr::str_extract()` is used to extract only the first occurrence to avoid catching the name of the month as well.

Answer (score 0):

My solution builds on Santosh's solution above, but solves the problem of multi-word countries by searching for each one individually.

```
  #remove punctuation
  raw2 <- gsub("[[:punct:]\n]","",raw)
  #get the list of countries we're searching for
  countries = sort(unique(tolower(world.cities$country.etc)))
  #this will be the discovery matrix
  raw3 <- matrix(0,nrow=length(raw),ncol=length(countries))
  colnames(raw3) = countries
  #search for each country by itself
  for(i in countries){
    ind = grep(i,tolower(raw2))
    raw3[ind,i] = 1
  }
  #result is an nxk matrix, where n is the number of obs in raw
  #and k is the number of countries (239 in my test)
  raw3
```